# Mobile landscape view makes my css divs of size 20% not be equal to a div of size 40%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm developing an HTML5 cross-platform mobile application. I'm using Bootstrap 3 for the design, but for the specific problem it has nothing to do with. Here is the problem:

I have a list of row divs, each having a col-xs-2 title div and a col-xs-10 content div. In the content div, I manually put divs of various width, based on percentage, but in most cases it is either 20, 40, 60, 80 or 100 %. Everything works alright, until when I rotate the mobile to landscape view. Only on some devices (!) there is a 1px difference between the width of a 40% div and the total width of two 20% divs. One 20% div is calculated to be 89px wide, while one 40% div is calculated to be 179px. The 40% div should have been 178px.

What can I do about this? It is important for me that the divs start and end at the exact same point. This 1px difference is killing. And it only shows up on certain devices (both Android and iOS). I suppose that it has something to do with the actual display size, but that doesn't reason browsers to miscalculate 40% and 2 * 20%. Anyway, what is your suggestion?

Thanks!!

Comment: Any fixed widths? paddings in the row? or margins in columns?

Comment: Also this might help on ios devices: `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">`

Comment: Pixel rounding...it happens.

Comment: I already have this: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
No paddings, no margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having happens because of fractionnal pixels being rounded differently...

Since a pixel cannot be cut in half, the browsers need to take decisions on what to do with 50% of an odd number of pixels. There is not too much to do about it though. You could use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if that's doable for you.

Here's a good read: http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/